# Laravel: how to write test for route Macro, Middleware and Model binding

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-routing, laravel-9

I build a simple way to identify tenant with subdomain, ex: `user1.example.com`, and tenant will be user1. On the other hand, if user1 does not exist, the `user1.example.com` will response `404`.

I define a `Macro` in service provider like following:

```php
/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('tenancy', function (Application $app) {
        return new TenancyMananger($app);
    });
}

/**
 * Bootstrap services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Route::macro('tenancy', fn (Closure $groups) => Route::domain(sprintf('{tenant}.example.com'))
        ->middleware(['tenancy'])
        ->group($groups));

    Route::model('tenant', Tenant::class);
}
```

Then, use `middleware` to init and identify the tenant:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    Tenancy::init($request->tenant);

    return $next($request);
}
```

And I override the `getRouteKeyName` method on the `Tenant model` to use database column other than `id`:

```php
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'domain';
}
```

Finally, I write the following feature testing case to test it:

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::tenancy(function () {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::get('/test', fn () => 'hello world');
});

$tenant = Tenant::factory()->create([
    'domain' => 'demo',
    'name' => 'demo name',
]);

$this->get('http://demo.example.com/test')->assertStatus(200);

$this->assertEquals(Tenancy::tenant()->id, $tenant->id);
$this->assertEquals(Tenancy::domain(), $tenant->domain);
$this->assertEquals(Tenancy::name(), $tenant->name);
```

But I will get the error:

```
testing.ERROR: App\TenancyMananger::init(): Argument #1 ($tenant) must be of type App\Models\Tenant, string given
```

It seems like that `route` does not trigger the model binding so that `$request->tenant` int the `middleware` pass the string ( subdomain ) into the `TenancyMananger`.

Any idea what could be happening here?
Or I can not write the test like this...

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

I use PHP 8.1, Laravel 10.x-dev and phpunit v9.5.27.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use this `Tenancy::init($request->tenant);` Laravel binds Model to the route. It would be best if you used something like

```
$tenant = $request->route('tenant');
Tenancy::init($tenant);

return $next($request);
```

And make sure you added `Tenancy` class to `$routeMiddleware`

Comment: I have added `Tenancy` class to `$routeMiddleware`, and change the way you mentioned like `Tenancy` class to `$routeMiddleware`. But, I still got the same error when run testing.

Comment: @ThomasYu Did you add `Tenant ` in `RouteServiceProvider` as well? `Route::model('tenant', Tenant::class);`

Comment: Yes, I add them in my service provider `TenancyServiceProvider`, and add `TenancyServiceProvider` to `config/app.php` as well.

Comment: Configs cleared and optimized? then it should work

Comment: Still not work and got the same error.